# How to add a column when its value is dependant on a different row's data in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table. I want to add a `flag` column, and set it to `1` on rows where the  temperature greater than previous day, and set it to `0` otherwise.

Input data is:

```
id  m_date      temp
-----------------------
1   2019-04-01  20
2   2019-04-02  25
3   2019-04-03  [NULL]
4   2019-04-04  24
5   [NULL]      25
6   2019-04-02  25
-----------------------
```

Desired output:

```
id  m_date      temp    flag
----------------------------
1   2019-04-01  20       0
2   2019-04-02  25       1
3   2019-04-03  [NULL]   0
4   2019-04-04  24       1
5   [NULL]      25       1
6   2019-04-02  25       0
----------------------------
```

Comment: How is `24` greater than `NULL`?

Comment: Why the flag is 0 for the record with id=6?

Comment: Why the flag is 1 for record with id=5 but 0 for id=1?

Answer (score 0):

> if temperature of row is greater than previous day'

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(temp) over (order by date) > temp
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from t;
```

This answers your question.  However, it does not return the same results because it is unclear what your rules are for `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT t.id
    , t.m_date
    , t.temp
    -- , p.m_date
    -- , p.temp
    , IF(
            t.temp IS NOT NULL
        AND (
               t.m_date IS NULL
            OR p.id IS NOT NULL -- previous day found
        )
        AND (
               p.temp IS NULL  -- no temp value for previous day
            OR t.temp > p.temp 
        )
    , 1, 0) AS flag
FROM
    temperature AS t
    LEFT JOIN temperature AS p ON (
        t.m_date = p.m_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    )
ORDER BY
    id
```

=>

```
id  m_date  temp    flag
1   2019-04-01  20  0
2   2019-04-02  25  1
3   2019-04-03  NULL    0
4   2019-04-04  24  1
5   NULL    25  1
6   2019-04-02  25  1   -- not as you require
```

As already mentioned, it is a bit unclear what is your requirements for NULLs or when there is no data for previous day.